# 3D array value assign and use rand() in C

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to build a fluid viscosity calculator.

For which using a 3D array to store value.

Users need to input 3 kinds of fluid and 3 kinds of object.

there will be 3 experiments to calculate the average viscosity of each object in each fluid.

the program will use rand() to generate the measured viscosity in each fluid of each experiment

How do I store the input of user and use rand() to generate the measured viscosity and store it in the same time?

> Here is the goal : array[fluid][object][measured value]

```
        fluid(1)                        fluid(2)                    fluid(3)
        object1 10 20 30                object1  13 25 33           object1  18 20 39
        object2 40 55 60                object2  44 55 66           object2  45 56 67
        object3 70 80 93                object3  77 88 99           object3  78 89 90
                  3x3                               3x3                         3x3
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int main(){ 
char arr[3][3][3];
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
for (int i=1;i<=3;i++){
        for (int j=1;j<=3;j++){
            scanf("%c",&arr[i][j][0]);
            arr[i+1][j][0]=arr[i][j][0];
            for (int k=1;k<=3;k++){
                      arr[i][j][k]=rand();
                     
               }

        }
}
       
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: "Here is what I've tried but it doesn't work." does not show input used.  Remember `'\n'` is a `char` too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick answer. Please reply if you need more details.

Simply change

```
for (int i=1;i<=3;i++)
```

to

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
```

That is because subscripts in programming languages start with 0 and end with [Array size] - 1.

You have to do the step above for j and k too, of course.

Edit: And as Reinstate Monica has pointed out (Thanks, by the way! :):

Try replacing

```
arr[i+1][j][0]
```

with simply

```
arr[i][j][0]
```

Comment: Review the `i+1` in `arr[i+1][j][0]`.